# BTC-e funding/withdrawal methods. Anybody tried any of these?

Tags: btce, withdrawal, funds

When one tries to deposit or withdraw, a dropdown list shows several choices, including Perfect Money, MoneyPolo, and OKPAY (and some other ones, including various cellphone-related ones with high fees, which I'm not interested in). If I'm not wrong, Mt. Gox supported OKPAY too, back in the day.

Has anybody tried any of these three and is willing to share their experience? (MoneyPolo and OKPAY are both owned by Mayzus, apparently, but I don't know what differences are there between them).

Also, if anyone knows there's another SE site where this question would be more likely to be answered, or somewhere else where I can find this info, it would be really helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

I am using perfectmoney there for funding there and it goes always instant to get credit my account balance, i think that is nice method to use there.